# Restoring accidentally deleted content type

Tags: 6, nodes

I am an absolute Drupal newbie, so please forgive my ignorance.

I have got an old Drupal site to manage (Drupal version 6.22).

While playing with the site I defined a new content type called **My page** and based on **page**.

After playing with it a bit I deleted it, from then on all my pages lost their content type and became uneditable.

After a lot of googling I realized that because **My page** was based on **page**, after deleting it I lost page type too. Seems a very strange logic to me, but not going to argue.

How can I restore the "page" content type? I tried to add it again, it was added OK, still all old pages remained typeless and uneditable.

The last site backup is from a couple of month ago and is irrelevant, as a lot of user content was added since.

I have an access as admin to the site's Drupal system, however I do not have a  remote access to the server. Should I request it? Where should I go and what should I change?

Comment: What do you mean "based on", there's no type of inheritance or such for content types. And deleting one content type doesn't delete another.

Comment: -1 on the "urgent help needed!" thing. That's what consultants are for, not a community that gives their time for free.

Comment: Removed. Unfortunately, I am not in a position to hire a consultant.I wish I would.

Comment: I created a new type with the same machine name as an existing one. Still deleting a new type should not affect an old one, but that is exactly what happened, and this logic seemed to me extremely wrong. And I am sure that is exactly what happened, because I didn't did anything else. Just created a type, checked that is is shown in menu and then deleted it.

Comment: Thanks, I realize most people asking here are not in a position to hire a consultant, just saying that one shouldn't (in my opinion) expect special treatment because one writes "urgent" in the title. Can't comment more on the missing content type than, "That shouldn't happen", and hasn't happened to me, ever, during all my years with different versions. Though it's of course possible to do such configuration on a specific site should that be desired. Could be that your site works that way, for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

If a content type has been deleted, possibly all content of that type have lost their type setting, and so even if the content type is recreated, they might not be recognized as belonging to that type.

This should go without saying, but clearly that's not the case. **Take a backup**, before you happen to make things even worse.

You'll need to manually update the `type` column of the `node` table to the machine name of the content type.

Comment: Thank you. How can I find this specific node table? Sorry if the question sounds silly,it is my first Drupal project, and obviously I started on the wrong foot.

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, other than "In the database". Where the database is I have no knowledge of, but it will be specified in the settings.php file, which in turn is somewhere under the /sites directory.